# nested Multidimensional darray angular model

Tags: angular

I'm developing a prototype to showcase how we could change our business model from a "box" driven market and turn it into a subscription business. We are using the platform Zuora central to manage our subscriptions. The data is provided via REST. (See https://www.zuora.com/developer/api-reference/#tag/Catalog). I'm using the data that I have called from ZUORA to adjust pricing.

I have following n-level datamodel:

```
export class OrderInTake {
  productID: string;
  productName: string;
  productRatePlans: ProductRatePlans[];
}

export class ProductRatePlans extends Products {
  'id': string;
  'status': string;
  'name': string;
  'description': string;
  'effectiveStartDate': string;
  'effectiveEndDate': string;
  'PriceType__c': string;
  'PriceCode__c': string;
  'CurrencyOfBasePrice__c': string;
  'BasePrice__c': string;
  'productRatePlanCharges': ProductRatePlanCharges[];
}

export class ProductRatePlanCharges extends ProductRatePlans {
    'id': string;
    'name': string;
    'type': string;
    'model': string;
    'uom': string;
    'pricingSummary': [];
    'pricing': Pricing[];
    'defaultQuantity': string;
    'applyDiscountTo': string;
    'discountLevel': string;
    'discountClass': string;
    'productDiscountApplyDetails': [ ];
    'endDateCondition': string;
    'upToPeriods': string;
    'upToPeriodsType': string;
    'billingDay': string;
    'listPriceBase': string;
    'billingTiming': string;
    'billingPeriod': string;
    'billingPeriodAlignment': string;
    'specificBillingPeriod': string;
    'smoothingModel': string;
    'numberOfPeriods': string;
    'overageCalculationOption': string;
    'overageUnusedUnitsCreditOption': string;
    'unusedIncludedUnitPrice': string;
    'usageRecordRatingOption': string;
    'priceChangeOption': string;
    'priceIncreasePercentage': string;
    'useTenantDefaultForPriceChange': string;
    'taxable': string;
    'taxCode': string;
    'taxMode': string;
    'FeatureCode__c': string;
    'triggerEvent': string;
    'description': string;
    'revenueRecognitionRuleName': string;
    'useDiscountSpecificAccountingCode': string;
}
```

when I need to access the sub sub array ProductRatePlanCharges I'm getting the error message: 
Property 'productRatePlanCharges' does not exist on type 'ProductRatePlans[]'.

I guess I need to change the model - How do I have to change the model in order to be able to access the sub sub array?

Background for the question: I need to push 2 new objects in each ProductRatePlanCharges to store next to the listprice and the default quantity a discounted price and a adjusted quantity. If there a smarter way to this instead of pushing the values for each rateplan please share.

thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your model `OrderInTake` has `productRatePlans` which is an array, then each items in array has another array called `productRatePlanCharges` so for accessing it you need to traverse like that

for example `OrderInTake.productRatePlans[0].productRatePlanCharges`  => and this will be the array too

or `OrderInTake.productRatePlans.forEach(item => item.productRatePlanCharges // do something with it)`